# NON-MVC application below MVCsite

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a very simple (not MVC) ASP.NET C# Web Form deployed as an application to our web server. Works perfectly.

An MVC application was added to our web server using another IP address and IIS site. We want the above Web Form to exist as an application within/below the MVC site. However, when we try to access the web form at https://mvcsite/webform.aspx we get:

```
The CodeDom provider type 
"Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, 
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.
```

with a reference to:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

in the web.config file for the MVC site.

We have tried adding

```
<system.codedom></system.codedom>
```

and

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers></compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

in Web Form web.config and neither resolved the issue.

Any suggestions - or an outright fix - would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try using an IFrame ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Why would I use an IFrame? The Web Form is completely stand alone. It does not render inside any other page or control.